# How to print output to a csv file?

Tags: python

I need help in writing code to print output to csv file. The code is posted below. Appreciate your help.

```
import csv

result = {}

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in result:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[1]]

print(result)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use `print` in this way, you just want to use the `writer` method of the `csv` library. If this is your own code for `reader` then you have more than enough understanding to implement the `writer`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer Check this out

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what have you tried already?

Comment: Provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: i am new to python,i used this sample code from other post to replicate my scenario,

Comment: import csv

result = {}

 

with open('dataout.csv', 'w') as new_file:
       fieldnames = ['col1','col2']
       csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file,lineterminator='\n')

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in result:
            result[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[1]]
print (result)
csv_writer.writerows(result)

Comment: so far i have this

Comment: please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv.writer` to write the rows in `result` to an output stream:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in result.items():
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Edited my answer as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @krishnaoadba Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it's correct?

Comment: Sure, i will be glad to do that,

Comment: i don't see accepted button any where on the screen, how do i do that ? pls advice

Comment: @krishnaoadba Thanks. Simply click on the grey check mark next to an answer. Please refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)